Pandas rolling min, corresponding value from other column
I have an index-like column whose value I want to report for the rolling min value. Here's the code:
d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ix':[0,1,2,3,4,5], 'val': [1,-2,5,4,9,6]})
d['first'] = d['val'].rolling(3).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] if not x.empty else None) 
d['min'] = d['val'].rolling(3).min()
d['ix_min'] = [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1, 3, 3] # this is what I actually want to compute
print (d)

 val  first  min  ix_min
 0    1    NaN  NaN     NaN
 1   -2    NaN  NaN     NaN
 2    5    1.0 -2.0     1.0
 3    4   -2.0 -2.0     1.0
 4    9    5.0  4.0     3.0
 5    6    4.0  4.0     3.0


Try:
d["ix_min"] = d["val"].rolling(3).apply(pd.Series.idxmin)
print(d)

Prints:
   ix  val  ix_min
0   0    1     NaN
1   1   -2     NaN
2   2    5     1.0
3   3    4     1.0
4   4    9     3.0
5   5    6     3.0


EDIT: Suppose you have this dataframe:
   ix  val
0  10    1
1  20   -2
2  30    5
3  40    4
4  50    9
5  60    6

Then you can do:
d["ix_min"] = d.set_index("ix")["val"].rolling(3).apply(pd.Series.idxmin).values
print(d)

Prints:
   ix  val  ix_min
0  10    1     NaN
1  20   -2     NaN
2  30    5    20.0
3  40    4    20.0
4  50    9    40.0
5  60    6    40.0


Thanks. But I want to take the value literally from the ix column (or whatever other column), rather than the index value, would this be achievable? Thanks
